# How to invoke ionide f# REPL

Tags: f#, atom-editor

I just installed atom and did "apm install ionide-installer". I already have Visual Studio and f# installed. No problem edit .fsx file, "Syntax highlighting" and "Error highlighting". But how can I invoke f# REPL? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Atom Editor focused hit Ctrl+Shift+P. That opens the Atom command window. Type fsi to show all the FSharp Interactive commands. You should see this:

[image: ATOM FSI commands]